# Prevent members from creating unique permissions

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am managing a SharePoint site and realise that under Permissions I have a lot of documents that have unique permissions.

After checking, I realise this is due to the way the users share the document where it will create unique permission to the folder.

I have some folders that have restricted access but these are changes done by me.
But the rest of the 50 over documents/folders shown with unique permissions are done by users.

I am wondering if changing the users' permission can result in a neater permission management. At the moment the members are using the default 'Edit' permission.

Answer (score 0):

There is a site level Permission Role called `Manage Permissions`

You will need to make a new permission level with `Manage Permissions` unselected if you want to limit all users from being able to break inheritance.

For Instance `Contribute(without Manage Permissions)`, and assign that to users or groups

Reference: [User permissions and permission levels in SharePoint Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sites/user-permissions-and-permission-levels)